# TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable on airflow auth

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to implement OIDC authentication in flask for airflow:

```
FULL_NAME_OIDC_FIELD = 'name'
EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

class AuthOIDCView(AuthOIDView):

    @expose('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login(self, flag=True):
        sm = self.appbuilder.sm
        oidc = sm.oid

        @self.appbuilder.sm.oid.require_login
        def handle_login():
            user = sm.auth_user_oid(oidc.user_getfield(EMAIL_FIELD))

            if user is None:
                info = oidc.user_getinfo(['last_name', 'email', 'role'])
                full_name = info.get(FULL_NAME_OIDC_FIELD)
                if " " in full_name:
                    full_name = full_name.split(" ")
                    last_name = full_name[1]
                else:
                    last_name = ""

                user = sm.add_user(
                    last_name=last_name,
                    email=info.get(EMAIL_FIELD),
                    role=sm.find_role('Admin')
    )

            login_user(user, remember=False)
            return redirect(self.appbuilder.get_url_for_index)

        return handle_login()
```

but it's been failing with this error

```
  File "/opt/airflow/webserver_config.py", line 39, in handle_login
    if " " in full_name:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

My understanding is `user` is returned empty from OIDC server but as we try to iterate on it, it fails because `None` is not iterable, is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

`info.get(FULL_NAME_OIDC_FIELD)` call returns `None` object. You need to first check if it's actually a string.